# Python method after create an object (resolved)

Tags: python, oop

Problem: I need a special Method in Python that is executed AFTER the Object is created.

Suppose i have a situation:

```
    ##-User Class;
    class User:
        __objList = []        ## User Class register of userObjs;
        __init__(self, name):
            self.name = name

    ##-and i create new UserObj;
    user = User("John Doe")
```

How can i add this UserObj in User.__objList[] after creation of Object user?
Is there a method in Python that executes after the object is initialized?
PS.I need add this usrObj in User.__objList after userObj was created by class automatically.

Comment: Take a look at the __init__ function

Comment: The `__init__()` magic method gets called *after* the object is created.

Comment: I already use this function (see the code example above). Until __init__() completes, all fields of the object will not be initialized. No? But i need 
fully initialized object.

Comment: Ok, thanks,  I'll try again.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question. Everything is working. The question is closed.

Comment: How i can add a solution with code? Im newbie, sorry :)

Comment: Sorry, im stupid.  The answer was obvious. Thanks for answers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add your code to the `__init__` function, when you create an object the code in the `__init__` function will run.

```
class User(object):
    __objList = []
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        # append object to list after create object
        self.__objList.append(self)

    @classmethod
    def showObjList(cls):
        for obj in cls.__objList:
            print("obj: (%s), name: (%s)" % (obj, obj.name))

a = User("Joy")
b = User("Hank")

User.showObjList()
```

[picture show result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJVt8.png)

Comment: Nick Li,  why do not you use a new style of formatting? I want to understand :)  print('{}, {}'.format(obj, obj.name))

Comment: We can use `format`, that's OK. I'm used to using `%s` when I write some  Domes.

Comment: Sorry for not thanking you. Your solution is what I needed :)