# Print statement only done once, but using more than one class instance

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am not able to understand this code and the concept behind such output. I am creating two objects but only one "Hello" is printed in console. I have tried to figure out through "id" but both the ids are different from each other:

```
class lol:
    print("Hello")        # Output: Hello
                          # 16377072 16378920
h = lol()
k = lol()
print(id(h), id(k))
```

Comment: `hello` is printed when you define the class, not when you create the objects.

Comment: If you want something to be done when you create a class instance, put it in the class's `__init__()` method.

Comment: The class body is executed when *defining* the class, not instantiating it. Why would you assume the ``print`` to run twice?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python method after create an object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48722512/6045800)

Answer (score 1):

"Hello" prints only once:
As is mentioned in a comment, since `lol` is a class, the `print` statement is only executed when the class definition is evaluated.

ids are distinct:
You are checking the unique id for the two objects h and k. Since these are distinct objects, their identifiers are unique.

Answer (score 1):

Anything in the class definition that's not inside a method function is executed once, at the time the class is defined.

When you create an instance of the class, its `__init__()` method is executed (if you define one). That's where you should put per-instance actions.

```
class lol:
    print("defining class")

    def __init__(self):
        print("creating instance")

h = lol()
k = lol()
print(id(h), id(k))
```

This should print:

```
defining class
creating instance
creating instance
16377072 16378920
```

(The numbers at the end will obviously be different.)